# How to display the outcomes with two space of tabs when there is a for loop

Tags: shell-script

I would like to create a code to obtain the following result:

```
echo -e "\t\tPlease enter your name?"
read name
name="${name,,}"
for i in $(echo "Hello " $name) ; do
    echo ${i^} 
done | sed 's/^/\t\t/;s/$/, here is your order:/'
```

If I enter the name like: `mike denver`

The output is:

```
<here come out the right space of two tabs>Hello, here is your order:
<here come out the right space of two tabs>Mike, here is your order:
<here come out the right space of two tabs>Denver, here is your order:
```

Basically, it create the right space from the left side based on the number of tabs that I put (`\t`), but it repeats the print line for `Hello` plus for each names entered. I didn't understand how to put sed command outside.
My expected result should be this:

```
<here come out the right space of two tabs>Hello, Mike Denver here is your order:
```

Comment: Rather than using a loop, just use the variable directly? `echo "Hello, ${name^}" | sed ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array for the name and `printf`:

```
read -p $'\t\tPlease enter your name?\n' -a name
name=( "${name[@],,}" )
printf '\t\tHello %s, here is your order:\n' "${name[*]^}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `for` loop, it's much easier to just do this:

```
echo -e "\t\tPlease enter your name?"
read -a name
name="${name}"
echo -e "\t\tHello ${name[@]^}, here is your order:"
```

Output:

```
            Please enter your name?
mike denver
            Hello Mike Denver, here is your order:
```

Double quotes around the argument for `echo` will expand the variable and print everything together at once in the desired format.